# Database design: product sizes

Tags: mysql, database-design

For a B2B shop I'm looking for the best database design. The products are stored in a database and every product have a size bar. This size bar has a unknown number of sizes where the product is available in. So, at this moment, we know the product and we know in which sizes the product is available. After this, it should be possible to add a unknown number of colors to the product and at the end, for every color / size combination, the stock amount should be stored.

Below, I've made the database design for it, but I think it isn't the best solution for it. The bottom line is that there will be entered orders. Almost every order has multiple products and almost all the color / size combinations. Could someone help with the best database design for it?

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
sizebar
--------
id, title

sizebar_sizes
--------
id, sizebar_id, size

products
--------
id, sizebar_id, title

products_colors
--------
id, product_id, color

products_sizes
--------
id, color_id, sizebar_sizes_id, quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want many-to-many relationships... 
product and size should have a pivottable products_sizes. product and color should have a pivottable products_colors

Another table could contain the items in stock for example: in_stock table with a foreign key to productID, colorID and sizeID

Comment: Ok, that is a possibility, but what about the orders? I could create a table named orders, with for every unique productID, colorID and sizeId a new row with the order quantity. But, the number of rows in that table will grow rapidly, so maybe there is a better solution for it?

Comment: true, it can become really big, but thats what databases are for right? Lots of data... You could add a sort of caching table that contains all the latest orders so you'll have fast access to them. Or maybe you could dump old orders to a file so that your table remains fairly small... By indexing your orders table you'd need a lot of orders before it becomes slow, I think caching the latest 'used' orders is your best bet if it truly is needed

Answer (score 0):

I can't really wrap my head around what a "sizebar" is, but if like you say each product has one and only one sizebar, then any sizebar data can be part of the products table.

Then you've got sizes:

```
sizes
--------
id, size
```

and colors:

```
colors
--------
id,  color
```

Products are still a generic, high level concept:

```
products
--------
id, title, sizebar_name
```

So we will need to know what specific variations are available right? I called it "items" but it could be "available_products" or "variations" or whatever:

```
items
--------
id, item_id, color_id, size_id
```

We will also need To track what items are ordered so we need orders:

```
orders
--------
id, client_id, order_date, shipping_type, etc etc
```

and

```
order_items
----------
id, order_id, item_id, quantity
```

Comment: A sizebar is a collection of multiple sizes. So there are just a few sidebars like:
1. s, m, l
2. m, l, XL
3. l, xl, xxl etc.
So, after producing a product, it fits one of the available sidebars. Your table structure is in general the same as mine. The main question is: is it possible to decrease the number of order_items since there is a sizebar which store all the available sizes?

Comment: So a sizebar could be its own table, but I don't think it should be so attached to the rest. You could use it to generate available items, but once a shirt is an "XL blue SportsTeamXJersey" it no longer matters what sizebar it came from right?

Comment: Now that I think about it you will also probably need an inventory_items table to track how many of each item you have, and ensure that it can be ordered.

Comment: Just saw your question in the comment above: no, you will need to track items and order items individually for things like stock level an quantity ordered, so trying to save space here isn't helping you. Also you will need to enumerate which sizes are available in which colors, negating any benefit.

Comment: That is correct, there is also a inventory table with the actual stock. But, developing the database like this, for a order with 20 products assuming that every product has 10 colors and every color have 5 sizes there will be added 1.000 rows to the database for only a single order. This is a lot, isn't it? There should be a better solution for it?

Comment: That's just as many rows as is necessary to discretely explain the data. Imagine i call up and say I want 1 sm white, 2 med white, 3 lg white, 4 xl white,  etc through all your products. You HAVE to have a record for each.

Comment: Ok, clear, thanks for the clear explanation. What about the speed of the database. If I make use of an index at all the reference id's like order_id, color_id etc. is the database fast enough with a million of order items?

Comment: Yes this kind of design is "index friendly" so it should make it very fast querying items in an order, orders over time, items available in a certain size, etc